# Need Free Multiple File Uploader Control with Ajax Update panel for Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, file-upload, updatepanel

I need a File Upload Control with multiple files in Ajax update panel. Dont Give me link of flash Uploader, it wont work with Ipad so it is not suitable for me. Please advice me some link to use with which i can Go further in my project.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the best file uploader control I found, no flash, multiple file upload, drag and drop support and (real) progress bar: http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

You can find an example project integrating with Asp.Net here:
 https://github.com/i-e-b/jQueryFileUpload.Net

Comment: Thanks, Exactly found what i want.. Appriciated.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can look at codeproject, Multiple file uploaded

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15742/Multiple-File-Upload-With-Progress-Bar-Using-Flash

or what about ? kcFinder http://kcfinder.sunhater.com/